# Runtime Error - C Programming , No Error on IDE

Tags: c, runtime

Here's the description of the problem https://a2oj.com/p?ID=193 , it works very well on Visual Studio but for some reason it produces Runtime - Error on the website's online judge compiler, it's hard for me to detect it since their compiler doesn't tell what was the test case produced the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ASCII_SIZE 255
void main(){
   int testCases;
   char caseInput[100];
   int count[ASCII_SIZE] = {0};
   int strLength;
   int max = -1;
   char result = NULL; 
    typedef struct occurrence{
        int numOfOcc;
        char occLetter; }Occurence;
    scanf("%d",&testCases);
    Occurence *ptr;
    ptr = (Occurence*)malloc(testCases * sizeof(Occurence));
    if (ptr){
    for (int caseValue = 0; caseValue < testCases; caseValue++)
        {
         scanf("%s",caseInput);
         strLength = strlen(caseInput);
         for (int i=0; i<strLength; i++)
             count[caseInput[i]]++;
         for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
             if (max <= count[caseInput[i]]) {
                 if (result > caseInput[i] && i > 0 ){
                 max = count[caseInput[i]];
                 result = caseInput[i];
                     }
                 else if ( i == 0 ){
                      max = count[caseInput[i]];
                      result = caseInput[i];
                     }

                 }
             }
         ptr[caseValue].numOfOcc = max;
         ptr[caseValue].occLetter = result;
         max = -1;
         char result = NULL;
         memset(count,0,sizeof(count));
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
        {
        printf("%d %c\n",ptr[i].numOfOcc,ptr[i].occLetter);
        }
        }
   }
```

Comment: I have seen this before with their compiler/test bed: your `void main()` is a pertinent wrong declaration and must be `int main`. As a result, your `main` returns an undefined value, which their test bed interprets as an error and so reports a run-time error. Have it return 0.

Comment: Yeah thanks i did that, but now it says wrong answer for some reason although it works very well on the IDE and it's bad that their compiler doesn't say which test case made the code fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store an input string with up to 100 letters in your buffer:

```
char caseInput[100];
```

You forgot to include the terminating `'\0'`

Not related to runtime error but probably still unintentionally:

```
max = -1;
char result = NULL;
memset(count,0,sizeof(count));
```

Here you define a second `result` hiding the previous definition.

Also probably not related to your problem:

```
void main()
```

is not correct. Make it

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main (int argv, char *argc[])
```

and return 0 on success.

Comment: i didn't really understand what you mean by " You forgot to include the terminating '\0' "

Comment: You might want to read the basics of strings in C again. A string like `"Hello"` takes 6 bytes of memory as all strings are zero-terminated, i.e. they have a trailing `\0`-byte at the end. If the test case enters a string with exactly 100 letters you will need 101 bytes where `scanf` can store the result. You only provide 100 bytes.

Comment: Yeah gotcha, i just needed to know what exactly i need to change